# Upload file into server

Tags: java, upload

i'm building app to upload image files into server using POST.

After many hours it started to works, but i have last issue.
After upload data, my new file have additional header:

```
    --cpPHHy2XlygEWv4fZndlhywQcKPxV33Qn0Z8EOf8^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"^M
Content-Type: image/jpeg^M
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary^M
^M
```

This header doesn't appear in oryginal file.

My upload code is:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        String urlParam = "http://www.modesa.pl/adminPanel/ajax-tab.php?id_product="+productId+"&id_category=0&token=c4c533d2825f8791a07265d812d62d90&tab=AdminProducts&action=addImage&ajax=1&qqfile=IMG_0599.jpg";

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlParam);
        File file = new File(filename);

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
        mpEntity.addPart("IMG_0599", cbFile);

        Header[] headers2 = {
                new BasicHeader("Cookie", cookieNew),
                new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        };

        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        httppost.setHeaders(headers2);
        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse responseX = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = responseX.getEntity();




        System.out.println(responseX.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
        if (resEntity != null) {
            resEntity.consumeContent();
        }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Can you help me, what to do, that those headers wont appear in new file ?

Comment: I answered a question a while ago that had the same problem. Heres the Q and A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985169/download-image-through-sockets-java/19985908#19985908

Comment: Could you show me, where exackly should i use \r\n ?