# Maven with JDK 11 fails when downloading a wrong dependency with "extension (10) should not be presented in server_hello"

Tags: java, maven, ssl, maven-plugin, java-11

Running test on my project with JDK11 I get failures at this line when calling Maven Aether:

- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/jmeter/mojo/ConfigureJMeterMojo.java#L643

This happens when downloading a wrong dependency :

> commons-math3:commons-math3

My hypothesis is that I am facing a [JDK11 bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210005) as per:

```
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016415/jdk-11-ssl-error-on-valid-certificate-working-in-previous-versions
```

If it's the issue, **How can this be workaround ?**

Stacktrace partly truncated due to stackoverflow limitation:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:DEV-SNAPSHOT:configure (configure) on project test-plugins: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_components:jar:2.13 -> org.apache.jmeter:jorphan:jar:2.13 -> commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1: Could not transfer artifact commons-math3:commons-math3:pom:3.4.1 from/to JBoss (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/): extension (10) should not be presented in server_hello -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:DEV-SNAPSHOT:configure (configure) on project test-plugins: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_components:jar:2.13 -> org.apache.jmeter:jorphan:jar:2.13 -> commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ...
[INFO] Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact commons-math3:commons-math3:pom:3.4.1 from/to JBoss (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/): extension (10) should not be presented in server_hello
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:365)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:259)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:498)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:261)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:539)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:522)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:411)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:507)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:460)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:256)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:282)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyTransitiveRuntimeDependenciesToLibDirectory (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:643)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyTransitiveRuntimeDependenciesToLibDirectory (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:674)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyTransitiveRuntimeDependenciesToLibDirectory (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:674)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.resolveTestDependenciesAndCopyWithTransitivity (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:577)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyExplicitLibraries (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:532)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyExplicitLibraries (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:515)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.doExecute (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:327)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.AbstractJMeterMojo.execute (AbstractJMeterMojo.java:233)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: extension (10) should not be presented in server_hello
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1068)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:962)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:567)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:435)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:412)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:453)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:259)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:498)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:261)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:539)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:522)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:411)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:507)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:460)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:256)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:282)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyTransitiveRuntimeDependenciesToLibDirectory (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:643)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyTransitiveRuntimeDependenciesToLibDirectory (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:674)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyTransitiveRuntimeDependenciesToLibDirectory (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:674)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.resolveTestDependenciesAndCopyWithTransitivity (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:577)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyExplicitLibraries (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:532)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyExplicitLibraries (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:515)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.doExecute (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:327)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.AbstractJMeterMojo.execute (AbstractJMeterMojo.java:233)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (10) should not be presented in server_hello
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException (Alert.java:128)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException (Alert.java:117)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:308)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:264)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:255)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init> (SSLExtensions.java:71)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloMessage.<init> (ServerHello.java:173)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.consume (ServerHello.java:864)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:392)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:444)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:421)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:178)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:164)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
[INFO]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute (MainClientExec.java:380)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:236)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:184)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:88)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:110)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:184)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:834)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:985)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:962)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:567)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:435)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:412)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:453)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:259)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:498)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:261)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:539)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:522)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:411)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:507)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:460)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:256)
[INFO]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:282)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyTransitiveRuntimeDependenciesToLibDirectory (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:643)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyTransitiveRuntimeDependenciesToLibDirectory (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:674)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyTransitiveRuntimeDependenciesToLibDirectory (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:674)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.resolveTestDependenciesAndCopyWithTransitivity (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:577)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyExplicitLibraries (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:532)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.copyExplicitLibraries (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:515)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.ConfigureJMeterMojo.doExecute (ConfigureJMeterMojo.java:327)
[INFO]     at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.AbstractJMeterMojo.execute (AbstractJMeterMojo.java:233)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
[INFO]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
[INFO]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Additional intro

Quick informative intro of the problem was provided by @cocorossello in his answer, I will only add that everything was started from the *Java Mailing List* [here >>](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2018-August/018005.html).

This message also includes a quick sample to reproduce the "issue":

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Fetch {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final URL targetURL = new URL("https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/media/jai-core/1.1.3/jai-core-1.1.3.pom");
        try (final InputStream is = targetURL.openConnection().getInputStream()) {
            is.read();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

---

### Client-side solution:

Issue is related to *JSSE* (*Java Secure Socket Extension*) module/library - the *Java* internal implementation for secure *SSL*/*TLS* connections.

**WORKAROUND**: So to workaround this issue we need to utilize different *SSL*/*TLS* implementation, e.g. [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)

I've created a small project in *GitHub* as a proof of concept: [jdk11-server_hello-workaround](https://github.com/marme1ad/jdk11-server_hello-workaround), main class is `FetchWorkaround.java`, which looks so:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class FetchWorkaround {

    private static final String HOST = "repository.jboss.org";
    private static final int PORT = 443;
    private static final String RESOURCE = "/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/media/jai-core/1.1.3/jai-core-1.1.3.pom";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TlsClientProtocol protocol = getTlsClientProtocol();
        sendRequest(protocol);
        readResponseStream(protocol.getInputStream());
    }

    private static void readResponseStream(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (TlsNoCloseNotifyException exception) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    private static void sendRequest(TlsClientProtocol protocol) throws IOException {
        OutputStream output = protocol.getOutputStream();
        output.write(("GET " + RESOURCE + " HTTP/1.1\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
        output.write(("Host: " + HOST + "\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
        output.write("Connection: close\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); // To force socket close immediately.
        output.write("\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); // HTTP 1.1 requirement: last line must be empty line.
        output.flush();
    }

    private static TlsClientProtocol getTlsClientProtocol() throws IOException {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(HOST), PORT);
        TlsClientProtocol protocol = new TlsClientProtocol(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream(), secureRandom);
        DefaultTlsClient client = new DefaultTlsClient() {
            public TlsAuthentication getAuthentication() throws IOException {
                TlsAuthentication auth = new TlsAuthentication() {
                    public void notifyServerCertificate(Certificate serverCertificate) throws IOException {
                    }

                    public TlsCredentials getClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest) throws IOException {
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                return auth;
            }
        };
        protocol.connect(client);
        return protocol;
    }

}
```

It connects to the host (the one from the `Fetch.java`) using a socket by defining `TlsClientProtocol` and sends `GET` request to the required resource (same *pom.xml*), the output looks so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:40:54 GMT
Server: Nexus/2.14.6-02
<... other headers ...>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  <... etc ...>
  <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jai-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <... etc ...>
```

So *pom.xml* was fetched successfully.

---

### Additional information

1. PoC shows that it is possible to handle *server_hello* related issue on the client-side, but it might be time-consuming (especially to replace *Aether* related logic).
2. In the answer to this [question >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985169/download-image-through-sockets-java) it is shown how to download binary data using sockets - just a helper method to handle headers on the top of the reponse.
3. **[Requires access to VM]** [Here >>](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation) is the manual how to set up *Bouncy Castle Provider* on the *Java* level.
4. **[Requires access to VM]** In case it is possible to update *JDK* on the VM (build/CI) side - it might be reasonable just to do a custom *JDK* build by using bug fix [PATCH >>](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/a8cf90dc8782) - it affects only `sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions` class - or just by using related [sources structure >>](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/a8cf90dc8782)

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSL 1.1.1 is more strict with the specification, so it's not strictly a bug, but it's something that will impact some users. It's solved in JDK 12 and targeted for JDK 11.0.2, so the patch will take a while (the backport is https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210005 ).

In my case I made a workaround using nginx as a "SSL proxy":

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myjbossrepository.mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host repository.jboss.org;
        proxy_pass https://repository.jboss.org/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

And then you will have to setup your repository URL as https://myjbossrepository.mydomain.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/

You can also use your own certificate if you want:

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name myjbossrepository.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/conf/letsencryptcertificates/live/myjbossrepository.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/conf/letsencryptcertificates/live/myjbossrepository.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host repository.jboss.org;
        proxy_pass https://repository.jboss.org/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a client workaround as I don't have control over the VM where build will happen.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in the Activiti project when trying to build with OpenJDK 11 due to a dependency on Drools which in turn tries to pull its own transitive dependencies from the JBoss repository rather than Maven central.

While the issue on the JBoss Nexus repo https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NEXUS-181 or JDK 11 is being addressed, I fixed on the client side by using a custom settings.xml file which sets [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) as a mirror of the jboss repo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <mirrors>
    <!-- use this mirror with OpenJDK 11 as a workaround for https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210005 and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NEXUS-181 -->
    <mirror>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group-central-mirror</id>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
      <mirrorOf>jboss-public-repository-group</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

and calling my build with: `mvn -s settings.xml install`