# Why am I getting a HTTP 400 bad request response when sending a manually-crafted HTTP request over a TCP socket?

Tags: java, http, httprequest, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to build an HTTP request manually (as a string) and send it over a TCP socket, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * SimpleHttpClient.java (UTF-8)
 *
 * Mar 27, 2014
 *
 * @author tarrsalah.org
 */
public class SimpleHttpClient {
    private static final String StackOverflow = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      if (args.length < 1) {
//          System.out.println("Usage : SimpleHttpClient <url>");
//          return;
//      }

        try {
            URL url = new URL(StackOverflow);
            String host = url.getHost();
            String path = url.getPath();
            int port = url.getPort();
            if (port < 80) {
                port = 80;
            }

            //Construct and send the HTTP request
            String request = "GET" + path + "HTTP/1.1\n";
            request += "host: " + host;
            request += "\n\n";

            // Open a TCP connection
            Socket socket  = new Socket(host, port);
            // Send the request over the socket
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            writer.print(request);
            writer.flush();
            // Read the response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String next_record = null;
            while ((next_record = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(next_record);
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleHttpClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleHttpClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this response message whatever the URL is chosen:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
```

Why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send HTTP Request manually via socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673684/send-http-request-manually-via-socket)

Comment: How about inspecting what you sent? HTTP Trace? Write to System.out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke) for the suggestion , I was missing tow space characters (One after the HTTP verb and the second after the path)

```
String request = "GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\n";
//                   ^            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually a bit unsure whether this solves your problem, but if you read [RFC2616, section 5](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) you will note that it very specifically mentions `CRLF`'s after `Request-line` and headers, so you might be missing some `\r`'s in your code.

Cheers,

Comment: Would that cause a 400?