# how to parse response when sending HTTP request manually through socket

Tags: java, sockets, http

This example:
[Send HTTP Request manually via socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673684/send-http-request-manually-via-socket)

describes very well how to send an HTTP request manually using a socket.
For sending, that's exactly what I need.
However, I could use some help with parsing the response. I.e. instead of having to deal with the flat response LOB I'd like to be able to invoke something like:

```
Response response = new Response(inputStream);
```

I looked at a few HTTP/Web service clients like JAX-RS or Apache Http Components that return a parsed response object but looks like they all expect the request to be submitted through the appropriate API.