# Request Timeout - socket Java

Tags: java, sockets

Having some problems with the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("ark.intel.com", 80);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            out.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                + "Host: ark.intel.com\r\n"
                + "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
                + "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36\r\n"
                + "Accept: text/html"
                + "\r\n");
            out.flush();

            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            String data = "";

            while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
                data += line;
                System.out.println(line);
            } read.close();
        } catch (Exception error) {}
    }
}
```

i keep getting

HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 11:43:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 218
Expires: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 11:43:41 GMT

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Request Timeout</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Request Timeout</H1>
The server timed out while waiting for the browser's request.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;2&#46;403b3717&#46;1517917421&#46;0
</BODY></HTML>
```

any idea on how to fix this?

Edit:
The host ark.intel.com is using HTTPS, i need to find a way to send the requests over HTTPS rather then HTTP.

Comment: The message is clear: the request takes too long to complete

Comment: but why is the request taking so long?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send HTTP Request manually via socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673684/send-http-request-manually-via-socket)

Comment: If you're trying to use 443, it's a completely different issue

Comment: So try to add the missing \r\n first

Comment: i added the \r\n, that fixed the problem (well sort of), now getting a 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' to 'Location: https://ark.intel.com/'.

Comment: Yeah, so you will indeed have to use HTTPS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing \r\n:

```
        + "Accept: text/html\r\n"
```

UPDATE

As we have seen, this will allow you to do the request, but you will get a redirect, forcing you to use HTTPS.

Try using an `HttpURLConnection` instead of plain sockets:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://ark.intel.com/");
        HttpURLConnection cnt = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        cnt.setRequestProperty("Host", "ark.intel.com");
        cnt.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        cnt.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");
        cnt.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");

        int stat = cnt.getResponseCode();
        if (stat != 200) {
            throw new IOException("HTTP error " + stat);
        }
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cnt.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String data = "";

        while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
            data += line;
            System.out.println(line);
        } read.close();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Host ark.intel.com is using https so you should use port 443.

```
Socket s = new Socket("ark.intel.com",443);
```

Then you will get another error, that will not be visible, because you are not handling exception

```
} catch (Exception error) {}
```

Here is example how to handle secure connections with use of SSL Socket: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/sockets/client/SSLSocketClient.java What you need to do is to change request with your parameters in this line out.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");

Comment: HTTPS is a little more complicated. Use an HttpUrlConnection instead of a plain socket.

Comment: Ok i changed the port number to 443, and added 'System.out.println(error)' to the catch. I now get the error 'java.net.SocketException: Connection reset'.

Comment: Here is example of use of SSL Socket. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/sockets/client/SSLSocketClient.java What you need to do is to change request with your parameters  in this line out.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");